# Is it correct to use "I myself" together

Tags: pronouns, reflexives

Is it correct to say "I myself will call you back"

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that some people would say this but it is pseudo-formal these days and rather clumsy-sounding in my opinion.

I prefer: "I will call you back myself."

Or: "I will call you back personally."

Note that the following ngram shows that not everyone agrees with my opinion. However you can see that the usage is declining slowly.

[Google ngram: I myself](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20myself&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20myself%3B%2Cc0)

[image]